# Proving a Cyclic Sum Inequality in a Euclidean Space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $(V; \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Euclidean space and let $\vec{x}$, $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{z}$ be nonzero vectors of $V$. Prove that
$$\sum_\text{cyc}{\left\lvert\frac{\langle\vec{z},\vec{x}\rangle\langle\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle}{\lVert\vec{x}\rVert}\right\rvert^{1/2}} \le \sum_\text{cyc}{\left(\frac{\lVert\vec{x}\rVert}{\lVert\vec{y}\rVert \lVert\vec{z}\rVert}\right)^{1/2}}\lvert\langle\vec{y},\vec{z}\rangle\rvert\,\text{.}$$

They tell us that we must use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the particular case of the usual Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$\left\lvert\sum_{k=1}^3{x_ky_k}\right\rvert \le \left(\sum_{k=1}^3{{x_k}^2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^3{{y_k}^2}\right)^{1/2}$$

Therefore, it is a question of conveniently choosing $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$ so that, using the previous inequality, we arrive at, or at least get very close to, the inequality proposed in the statement. The cyclical nature of the sums must be taken into account.
It may be convenient to put
$$x_1 = \sqrt{\lVert\vec{x}\rVert\cdot\lvert\langle\vec{y},\vec{z}\rangle\rvert}, \qquad x_2 = \sqrt{\lVert\vec{y}\rVert\cdot\lvert\langle\vec{z},\vec{x}\rangle\rvert}, \qquad x_3 = \sqrt{\lVert\vec{z}\rVert\cdot\lvert\langle\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle\rvert}$$
and similar expressions for $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$; for the assignment of the $y_k$ we are guided by the cyclical character of the sum of the left hand side of the proposed inequality.

Request for help.

Comment: Also the title is supposed to represent the question. Ending the title in the middle of a sentence is at least unclear. Please update your title.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|\langle \overset{\rightarrow}{x},\overset{\rightarrow}{y}\rangle |= ||\overset{\rightarrow}{x}||||\overset{\rightarrow}{y}|| \cos \theta_1, |\langle \overset{\rightarrow}{y},\overset{\rightarrow}{z}\rangle |= ||\overset{\rightarrow}{y}||||\overset{\rightarrow}{z}|| \cos \theta_2, |\langle \overset{\rightarrow}{z},\overset{\rightarrow}{x}\rangle |= ||\overset{\rightarrow}{z}||||\overset{\rightarrow}{x}|| \cos \theta_3,$ where $0\le \theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3\le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Then the desired inequality is equivalent to showing $$\sum_{cyc} (\cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_3)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le \sum_{cyc} \cos \theta_2.$$ This is just a simple application of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, $$\sum_{cyc} \cos \theta_2=\left(\sum_{cyc} \cos \theta_1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_{cyc} \cos \theta_3\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \ge \sum_{cyc}(\cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_3)^{\frac{1}{2}}. \quad \blacksquare$$

Comment: But here you are not proving the problem

Comment: It has been proven, the Inequality you want to prove is equivalent to the first Inequality above and the Inequality follows from the application of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality